The pumping length for language $(0 \cup 1)^*$ is 1 . T/F
This is a true or false question. True/False: The pumping length for language $(0U1)*$ is 1.
The answer is False, but I am quite confused.
I thought the pumping length for this language would be 1 because it recognizes any string with any number of 0 or 1.
However, this statement is false according to my exam. Then what would be its pumping length if 1 isn't the answer? I understand that this language can accept all possible strings of 0s and 1s. Let me know if it's a misunderstanding.
Or is it saying that the pumping length can be any number not necessarily 1, and that's why the statement is false?

This question might be more appropriate for another forum, like computer science: https://cs.stackexchange.com/.  You may get a better response there, as your question is related to automata theory.

@ad2004 I see what you mean here. I ask the question in this forum simply because they support latex notation in the body. I also saw there's a tag like pumping Lemma. Thanks for the reminding.
